# ImageView goes outside parent boundaries?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development here, but I seem to be having a really simple problem.  I'm trying to lay out the screen with three linear layouts, top taking up 12.5%, middle 73% and bottom 14.5%.  In the top region, I want to put a relative layout, with an ImageView inside the top linear layout.  (There's a lot more to this layout, with buttons and everything, but I stripped it down to show the problem).

If I remove the ImageView, everything blocks out perfectly and I get nice rectangular regions of the correct size.  But with the ImageView, the height of the top linear area expands to be 3/4 of the screen at least!

I want the RelativeLayout to stay inside the top linear area.  Any ideas?

By the way, my drawable/top_bar is natively 800px wide by 186px tall.

Here's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/masterLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearTop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".125"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topToolbarRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/top_bar" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearMiddle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight=".730">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight=".145">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the scale factor to fitXY. Something like :

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested it. Change ImageView to following:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/top_bar" />
```

Comment: That definitely works, I'm just confused why 'fill_parent' doesn't really mean fill parent!

Comment: that's why "fill_parent" [is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) since API Level 8.